# Splitting an XML file into multiple xml files in mule4

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I am using mule 4 and I am trying to split an xml file into multiple files with same header tag.

Input:

```
<Data>
  <Header>
  </Header>
  <Details-1>
    <Item-1>
    </Item-1>
  </Details-1>
  <Details-2>
    <Item-2>
    </Item-2>
  </Details-2>
</Data>
```

Expected Output:

File-1:

```
<Data>
  <Header>
  </Header>
  <Details-1>
    <Item-1>
    </Item-1>
  </Details-1>
 </Data>
```

File 2:

```
<Data>
  <Header>
  </Header>
  <Details-2>
    <Item-2>
    </Item-2>
  </Details-2>
</Data>
```

Tried writing in for-each scope but it either reads only Details tags or only first Details

Can someone help me in achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get your payload and filter out fields one by one. It could be done in one Transformation as multiple variables.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml  inlineCloseOn="empty"
var x=read('<Data>
  <Header>
  </Header>
  <Details-1>
    <Item-1>
    </Item-1>
  </Details-1>
  <Details-2>
    <Item-2>
    </Item-2>
  </Details-2>
</Data>','application/xml') 

var removeKey = (element,keyName) ->
  element mapObject (value, key) -> {
(if (key ~= keyName) {} else (
    (key): if (value is Object)
    removeKey ( value default {} , keyName )
else value
)
)
  }
---
removeKey(x,'Details-1')
```

output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Data>
  <Header/>
  <Details-2>
    <Item-2/>
  </Details-2>
</Data>
```

https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/FilterOutXmlFields.html